# How do i find a maximum value of a stock and return the day it occurred

Tags: r, max

I have a small dataset of daily return of stocks and I have to write a function which finds the highest return and extracts the day it occurred. Any suggestion how I do so?

This is the dataset:

```
> df
    VWD_RET       DATE Daily_Return
1  0.009312 2015-03-20          Fri
2 -0.001045 2015-03-23          Mon
3 -0.004701 2015-03-24          Tue
4 -0.014949 2015-03-25          Wed
5 -0.002183 2015-03-26          Thu
6  0.002501 2015-03-27          Fri
7  0.011713 2015-03-30          Mon
8 -0.007162       <NA>         <NA>
>
```

Comment: I think the answer is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743622/finding-row-index-containing-maximum-value-using-r

Comment: thanks, but i dont think this is the answer. actually i need to find the max value on the "VWD_RET" and to get an answer that says "Monday"(which is the highest value). i have tried to do something like that: max(df$VWD_RET, by=df$Daily_Return), but get NA as an answer..

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of options to practice R syntax

> **Base package**

```
df[which.max(df$VWD_RET), 3]
df[df$VWD_RET == max(df$VWD_RET), 3] # Similar to R.Schifini
df[order(-df$VWD_RET),3][1] # data frame in descending order
```

Output:

```
[1] "Mon"
```

> **dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% slice(which.max(VWD_RET)) %>% select(Daily_Return)
```

Output:

```
  Daily_Return
1          Mon
```

Ordering by `VWD_RET`in descending order and selecting `Daily_Return`.

```
arrange(df, desc(VWD_RET))[1, 3]
```

Output:

```
[1] "Mon"
```

> **sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Daily_Return, max(VWD_RET) from df")[1]
sqldf("SELECT Daily_Return
      FROM df
      ORDER BY VWD_RET DESC
      LIMIT 1")
sqldf("select Daily_Return from df 
      where VWD_RET in (select max(VWD_RET) from df)")
sqldf("SELECT Daily_Return
      FROM df
      WHERE  VWD_RET=(SELECT MAX(VWD_RET) FROM df)")
```

Output:

```
  Daily_Return
1          Mon
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
df$Daily_Return[ df$VWD_RET == max(df$VWD_RET) ]
```

The expression `df$VWD_RET == max(df$VWD_RET)` will return a vector of TRUEs and FALSEs, being true only on those values that are equal to the maximum.

Comment: thanks a lot, thats working :-)